# Google form fillable table

Tags: google-forms

How can we add a fillable table with rows and columns to Google Forms?

I want to add a fillable table to the Google form. It should consist of rows and columns. The form creater should have previlage to add both columns and rows to the table and the user should be able to enter inputs to both rows and columns. Is there any method to do this?Take this image as a example what i want to create.[image]

Comment: 1) The term “fillable table” can have many meanings. Would you please edit the question to include a specific example of the table that you want. 2)  This is a popular topic. Would you please edit the question to summarise your research prior to posting this question. 3) Recommendations for add-ons is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Google Forms does not have a feature that will produce a "fillable form" similar to the image included in the question.

There are often workarounds for many Google Forms features but the option in this case would be an HTML form.

The image included in the question is sourced from [JotForms](https://www.jotform.com/answers/3459734-table-formatting-for-forms). JotForms and Google Forms are different products and do not share the same features.

The question asks about add-ons for Google Forms, but recommendations of this type are off-topic for SO.